# Select objects with custom property

Tags: python

I am trying to select all objects with a custom property with a given value but with no success. The custom property is "category" and the value is "Windows". This is what I have tried. Any ideas?

```
    for obj in bpy.context.visible_objects:
        if bpy.data.objects[str(obj.name)]["category"]=="Windows":      
            obj.select_set(True)
```

There might also be variants of "Windows" so wildcards would be useful.

Comment: If you want to setup custom lookup rules for the property names I suggest you look up regex (regular expressions) they're daunting at first but really powerful.

Answer (score 3):

```
for obj in bpy.context.visible_objects:
    if "category" in obj:
        if obj["category"] == "Windows":      
            obj.select_set(True)
```

Comment: If you allocate a custom property to `bpy.types.object` then every object will have that property and your first `if` will always return `True`.